# Is there a way to manipulate the following string using C#?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

I want to manipulate the following HTML structure using C#, and move the bgcolor attribute inside the style attribute as shown below, I want to achieve it using string manipulation (Or any other suitable method if applicable) is there a way possible:

**Present Structure**

```
<body>
    <div bgcolor="#342516" style="color: red; font-size:10px;">ABCD</div>
    <div bgcolor="#342516" style="color: red; font-size:10px;">EFGH</div>
    <div bgcolor="#342516" style="color: red; font-size:10px;">HIJK</div>
    <div bgcolor="#342516" style="color: red; font-size:10px;">LMNO</div>
</body>
```

**Required Output**

```
<body>
    <div style="background-color:#342516; color: red; font-size:10px;">ABCD</div>
    <div style="background-color:#342516; color: red; font-size:10px;">EFGH</div>
    <div style="background-color:#342516; color: red; font-size:10px;">HIJK</div>
    <div style="background-color:#342516; color: red; font-size:10px;">LMNO</div>
</body>
```

Comment: There are numerous ways. You could treat it as a string and use `Regex.Replace`, but I would think that the most sound option would be to treat it as actual HTML and modify it that way, which you could probably do with the HTML Agility Pack, if that's still a thing. Where is it coming from exactly?

Comment: The data is being fetched by an API call, and needs to be manipulated and posted back, with the above mentioned edit.

Comment: I second the HTML Agility Pack.  https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack/

Answer (score 0):

If You really need it in C# the most simple solution is string.replace(). for any other more complex text You need regular expression

```
    var oldString = "<body>\r\n    <div bgcolor=\"#342516\" style=\"color: red; font-size:10px;\">ABCD</div>\r\n    <div bgcolor=\"#342516\" style=\"color: red; font-size:10px;\">EFGH</div>\r\n    <div bgcolor=\"#342516\" style=\"color: red; font-size:10px;\">HIJK</div>\r\n    <div bgcolor=\"#342516\" style=\"color: red; font-size:10px;\">LMNO</div>\r\n</body>";
    var newString = oldString.Replace("bgcolor=\"#342516\" style=\"", "style=\"background-color:#342516; ");
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you need to program to solve this, a text editor will suffice. As far as I know, both VS Code and NotePad++ support replacing text by folder.

> Replace **bgcolor="#342516" style="** with **style="background-color:#342516;**

Comment: This was an example, there is huge data which is being fetched by an API, and has to be manipulated in this way and then posted back, so the solution you provided doesn't work !